# Why is the "Transform all T4 Templates" not executing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, t4

I have a solution with three .NET Core 2 projects. Inside of every project I have several .tt T4 Templates.

I was searching for a smart way to transform all templates at once and found the **Transform All Templates**-Command.

Unfortunately the command does nothing. If I execute it in my solution, the output says:

```
Transforming templates for all project items.
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
Text templating transformation complete.
```

But after I check my templates, they did not update.
If I go to one template file and save it, it always transforms, but only this template. I have 20 templates and do not want to go to every file seperately.

Any ideas, why the command does not work?

Comment: How are you updating those templates? They should recompile automatically each time you update through Visual Studio

Comment: The templates are consuming a .json File, that changes sometimes. Almost all my models depend of this .json file. If I change the .json I want all templates to re-process...

Comment: I'm suffering the same thing on a dotnetcore 2.0 project: I have 4 tt's spread over 3 projects, which generate fine when changing the tt, or right-clicking, but not when invoking "Transform All Templates"

Comment: [T4Executer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TimMaes.ttexecuter) does this. You can specify to run all templates before or after building your solution.

Comment: @Epsilekt this question is about the "Transform All Templates" Command, not about paying the payload compiling them on every build. David, did you ever found a solution? I have some T4 templates in classic .net and some templates in .net standard. The classic ones are compiled. The .net standard ones aren't compiled (except explicit save).

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I understand, but that extension has a quick 'run all templates' icon on the solution explorer menu, if he keeps having this issue it could be a alternative untill this is resolved.